# Color lines in plotly r separately from markers

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to find a way to maintain the color of the line in my plotly graph, even if the marker colors change. I will explain... an example dataset:

```
mtcars$vs<-as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars$gear<-as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$Date<-sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2018/01/01'), by="day"), 32)
```

I made a plot that I want:

```
pal <- c("red", "blue", "green")

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>%
  mutate(fit = fitted(loess(mpg ~ as.numeric(Date))))%>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, 
          colors=pal, showlegend = T) %>%
  add_markers( y = ~mpg, color= ~vs, alpha = 0.4) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fit, color = ~vs,line=list(width=4), colors=pal) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title="Date"), title="All")
```

which gives me
[image]

When I change the marker input like:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>%
  mutate(fit = fitted(loess(mpg ~ as.numeric(Date))))%>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, 
          colors=pal, showlegend = T) %>%
  add_markers( y = ~mpg, color= ~gear, alpha = 0.4) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fit, color = ~vs,line=list(width=4), colors=pal) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title="Date"), title="All")
```

But then the line colors also change, I would like them to stay green en red..
[image]

I have tried to put "colors" on different locations in the script. I also saw posts where they added `add_trace` and I tried different things with filtering the data in add_trace, but it gave an error so I am not doing it the right way..

Could anyone help me? Would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Really a bit silly really, just used the wrong color code:

```
df1<-mtcars%>%  
  filter(vs=="0")%>%
  mutate(fit1 = fitted(loess(mpg ~ as.numeric(Date))))

df2<-mtcars%>%  
  filter(vs=="1")%>%
  mutate(fit2 = fitted(loess(mpg ~ as.numeric(Date))))


  plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~Date, 
          showlegend = T) %>%
  add_markers( y = ~mpg, color= ~vs) %>%
  add_lines(data=df1, y = ~fit1, line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 88, 229)')) %>%
  add_lines(data=df2, y = ~fit2, line = list(color = 'rgb(226, 124, 6)')) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title="Date"))

  plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~Date, 
          showlegend = T) %>%
    add_markers( y = ~mpg, color= ~gear) %>%
    add_lines(data=df1, y = ~fit1, line = list(color = 'rgb(22, 88, 229)')) %>%
    add_lines(data=df2, y = ~fit2, line = list(color = 'rgb(226, 124, 6)')) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title="Date"))
```

Must be a quicker way to do it, but at least it works :)